# How share new dynamically created folders?

Tags: linux-mint, nfs

I developed an app in java, and this app run on Apache Tomcat 9. My app create some folder and files dynamically. I want to share this files and folders via NFS. NFS config is as follow:

```
/home/noor/Public/Flight24 *(rw,async,no_root_squash,subtree_check)
```

for creating file via tomcat, I config folder sharing as follow:

[image]

The problem is sharing created dynamically directories. From NFS Client system I try  to read new created folder, It error permission access.

[image: Windows cannot access]

**How Do I Share new created folders?**

Comment: Are you sure Windows is using NFS and not SMB? Why are you using NFS shares rather then SAMBA,,ones?

Answer (score 0):

This happened because the dynamically created directory it is not exported by the NFS server, it is contained in the exported FS `/home/noor/Public/Flight24`.

To be mounted directly from a remote NFS client the folder have to be exported by NFS.

A possible solution may fit your exigence is to do not declare one by one in the `/etc/exports` but write a new function in your code which exports the folder once is created and remove the export before delete (if needed).
an example of exportation without file:

`exportfs -o rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check *:/exports/opt` <- **BE AWARE CHECK DOCUMENTATION I DO NOT KNOW IF WILDACRD WORKS HERE**

If the exportation have to be persistent you can append it in the `/etc/exports` file and re-load the exportation with `exportfs -a`